# What are the differences between LIME and SHAP as model interpretation techniques?

Tags: interpretation, shapley-value, lime

Model interpretation has been an important area of study nowadays and because of that some different techniques have risen to help on this task. Maybe the two most famous ones are [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) and [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap).

How would you explain the main differences between the two methods in a simple way?

And in which situations one method would maybe be better suited than the other?

Comment: I would guess that the fact that SHAP is based on game theory is maybe an important particularity that can derive important (and different) comprehensions regarding other methods like LIME, but I'm not so sure on which other important details they can be separated apart from each other.

Comment: Partially answered: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379744/comparison-between-shap-shapley-additive-explanation-and-lime-local-interpret